# JQuery Mobile in iOS project without phonegap

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, uiwebview

*Before I start, please don't yell at me telling me the answer is here or there, all my researches are polluted with phonegap results, and I don't use it, so I have troubles finding the answer !*

I'm currently developing a **native** iOS app. It's almost done, except one section, which will contain a **lot** of text (basically all the rules of a sport, 10 sections with 2 to 18 sub-sections and a lot of text in each). I started the implementation, using a UITableViewController to display the main sections, and selecting a cell brings me to another UITableViewController with all the sub-sections of the selected section. Then, selecting a sub-section, you're supposed to get its content. What I've started to do is use another UITableVC with TextViews in the cells, using section headers to structure the text, but that's **really** not convenient nor is it nice to read.

So, I want to use html pages in UIWebViews. I'm thinking of using JQueryMobile, as I've used it in the past and I think you can get nice results pretty quickly. So, I have a couple of questions :

1. First, what do you think of the structure of this section ? (a UITableVC sending to another UITableVC, bringing up a UIWebView). How can I do something as readable as possible ? It's really the first time I have to put that much text in an app, so I'm not as sure of my design as when I develop more "standard" things. I want to do something better, but I have **no** idea how I can do something better..
2. Secondly, is JQuery Mobile a good option ? And this brings the real question : **how do I include JQuery Mobile in my app ?** I know I can include the .js and .css directly from JQuery's servers, but my app can run offline, so where should I put the needed files ? How do I include them in the html files ?

Thanks for your help, and again, if the second question has been asked/answered, I'm sorry, but when you search for *JQuery Mobile* and *iOS*, all you get is PhoneGap questions..

Just in case :

> XCode 4.5.1
>
> iOS 5+
>
> Storyboard
>
> ARC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Becuase `UIWebView` objects will cost a lot of memory, it's better to have only one `UIWebView` object in the native view. Don't add it for each row of `UITableViewController`.

You can write the web pages and include jQuery Mobile as normal and test them on Mobile Safari (by starting a server on your Mac and access it in your iOS device/emulator). After testing, add the directory in your XCode project as the blue 'folder reference'. Use the following code to load the page in `UIWebView`:

```
NSString *baseDirectory = [[NSBundle mainBundle].resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"your_directory"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your_index.html" relativeToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:baseDirectory]]
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:3600];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear, I do not plan on replacing the UITextViews with UIWebViews but the last UITableViewController with a UIWebViewController ! Thanks for answering question number 2 ! I thought there would be some kind of setup process, linking libraries and stuff, but apparently not so that's good.

Comment: Sorry for "reoppening" the question, but it seems like my UIWebView can't find the .js files. The html pages are therefor not formatted. Any idea ?